# C++ - temporary variables and their lifetime

Tags: c++, qt, variables, destructor, lifetime

*This question can be considered a follow-up to the following question: [C++ temporary variable lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540157/c-temporary-variable-lifetime).*

`Qt` containers support the `stream-like` initialization syntax. Now, when I write the following code, my `QVector` is destructed right after assignment and the reference becomes dangling.

```
const QVector<QString>& v = QVector<QString>() << "X" << "Y" << "Z";
```

---

Corresponding `operator<<` is implemented the following way:

```
inline QVector<T> &operator<< (const T &t)
{ append(t); return *this; }
```

As far as I know, `10.4.10 Temporary Objects` states that the lifetime of a temporary object is extended to match the lifetime of the correspnding `const` reference to it.

However, in this case the temporary object `QVector<QString>()` **is destructed earlier.**

I guess that probably this happens due to the fact that the last operation returns a `QVector<QString>&` and shouldn't know anything about the lifetime of the temporary `QVector<QString>`, but this explanation isn't strict and might be wrong.

**So, why does this happen?**

Comment: "*I guess that probably this happens due to...*" You're roughly correct, but the technical explanation would be that an rvalue is decaying into an lvalue.

Comment: I think, the `temporary` is bound to the *returned* reference of *operator <<* but at the end of the `expression` it is destroyed. The standard only guarantees `temporary` bound to *const ref*'s life time, not `temporary's references` bound to them.

Comment: I realize your question satisfies academic curiousity, but practically, you can just make `v` not-a-reference like this: `const QVector<QString> v = QVector<QString>() << "X" << "Y" << "Z";`

Comment: @Robᵩ : There are subtleties here that are not purely academic, e.g. `for (auto foo : QVector<QString>() << "X" << "Y" << "Z") { ... }` doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lifetime of a temporary is only extended if it is bound to a const-reference:

```
const QVector<QString>& v = QVector<QString>();
```

However, in your code you are *not* binding the temporary to anything. Rather, you're calling a member function (of the temporary), which returns a reference (to the temporary). The result of this function call is no longer a temporary object, but just a plain reference. The original temporary object expires at the end of the full expression in which it appears, and the reference `v` becomes dangling.

(In the new C++, it is possible to prohibit such "accidents" by virtue of rvalue-qualified member functions, i.e. you could `=delete` the rvalue version of the `<<` operator.)